# Error when trying to comit the angular project on git

Tags: angular, git, angular-cli

command git add .
I am getting warning

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .husky/pre-commit.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

`git commit -m "Improvement for homepage, how it works, and start a boycott page"`
I am getting error

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "test"        
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Comment: For the first warning, try to run this command : 
git config --global core.autocrlf false

Comment: what about the error? how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all look at your file with husky pre-commit hook, located `.husky/pre-commit`. Inside you find see typical npm command, like `npm run test`. You have an error `Missing script: "test"`, which means this script invokes on commit, but not exists in your `package.json`.